# ng-packagr function calling issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

I have created a 3rd party component library using ng-packagr. We have referred to this article for creating the library.

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

We can import and render the components in the host application. But we are unable to call any function of the library in the host application. It is throwing the following error -

//node_modules/xxx.component.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.

Is there any way to achieve the same using ng-packagr?

import {sampleComp} from "library";

@ViewChild(sampleComp) comp:sampleComp; comp.callFunction();

Comment: Can you please add more details on "Unable to call function in the library"? What is your file structure? Is the function part of component or a separate file? Is it properly exported?

Comment: @byjoshi - The function is part of the component. It is getting properly exported.

Comment: @byjoshi - The library has been installed in the host application by using npm install. But the .ts files in the library are not getting compiled. I have add tried adding the files in tsconfig.json and also in angular.json , but with no avail.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add sample code for how are you accessing the function in the host application and how the function is defined in the component library.

Comment: I am importing the component in the host application using the normal import keyword. In the host application's ts file . I am trying to create an object of the component to access it's function.

Comment: import {sampleComp} from "library";

@ViewChild(sampleComp)
comp:sampleComp;

comp.callFunction();

Comment: I will give this scenario a try and let you know. I would suggest you to add information from above comments to the main question. It will be likely that other readers miss this information from comments.